# Putting data from AJAX call in handlebars variable

Tags: ajax, node.js, dynamic, handlebars.js

I have an HBS file which is getting data from a route and parsing it for display.

```
<div id="listContainer">
<ul id="expList">
{{#each hierarchy}}
        <li id="{{@key}}" class="{{@key}} cyclops-index collapsed" >{{@key}}
            <ul>
                {{#each this}}
                        <li value="{{@key}}" id="{{@key}}" class="{{@key}} cyclops-country expanded hide" >{{@key}}
                            <ul>
                                {{#each this}}
                                        <li value="{{@key}}" id="{{@key}}" class="{{@key}} cyclops-region expanded hide" >{{@key}}
                                            <ul>
                                                {{#each this}}
                                                        <li value="{{@key}}" id="{{@key}}" class="{{@key}} cyclops-cluster hide" >{{@key}}
                                                        </li>
                                                {{/each}}
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                {{/each}} 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</div>
```

Where {{{hierarchy}} is the handlebars variable. I have some buttons which when clicked should change this list that I am dynamically generating. For that I am using AJAX calls from those buttons to get the data without a page reload.

The problem is how to pass that AJAX data that I am obtaining from the call to the Handlebars variable `hierarchy`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to compile your Handlebars template on the client-side and call the resultant method after each time the AJAX data is received.

Comment: Alternatively, you could return the interpolated HTML in your AJAX response and swap it into the DOM.

Comment: @76484 Can you please give a small sample code to implement this? Just to give me a heads up as to how to start with this.

Comment: Can you share the server-side code that renders the Handlebars template and the code that handles the AJAX request?

Comment: Right now i am doing rs.render('hbs filename', {'hierarchy': value}); to send data to the hbs file right now. But instead of res.render, i want to use res.send so that it send the data of ajax call to the hbs file. Even this step is working. What i am not able to figure out is how to send the data that i get after the ajax call into the handlebars variable {{hierarchy}}.

Comment: If you want to use Handlebars on the client you will need to include the Handlebars JS in your page and you will need the compiled templates available in your client-side JS.

Comment: Can you please show a little example of how it can be done? I tried it but not been able to figure out how to compile the templates and send this data from the ajax to the compiled template.